# How to transfer boolean value between activities in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

This is how I am currently doing it but, it just force closes app.

In the first activity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Input.this, results.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("perfect", rig);
    startActivity(myIntent);`
```

Activity I want to transfer to

```
    Boolean lovers = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("perfect");
```

Comment: according to the answer of @PearsonArtPhoto you can use the getBooleanExtra method. But actually there is no fault in your own code. It should work perfectly. So the code you have pasted in your question is not crashing the app. so you better paste the logcat data after the app crashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I am not sure about the accepted answer**:: *But i think it should be*

```
Boolean lovers = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("perfect");
```

Comment: You are correct. getExtras() returns a Bundle and Bundle does not have getBooleanExtra() method.

Answer (score 5):

As [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) say, the function is `getBooleanExtra`

```
Boolean lovers = getIntent().getExtras().getBooleanExtra("perfect");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this at sending side:

```
MyModel model = new MyModel();

 //1. using constructor
    Boolean blnObj1 = new Boolean(model.getBooleanStatus()); // This //getBooleanStatus will return 'boolean' value

    //2. using valueOf method of Boolean class. This is a static method.
    Boolean blnObj2 = Boolean.valueOf(model.getBooleanStatus());
  }

Intent targetIntent = new Intent(MyCalass.this, TargetClass.class);
targetIntent.putExtra("STATUS", new Boolean(model.getBooleanStatus()));
targetIntent.putExtra("STATUS", Boolean.valueOf(model.getBooleanStatus()));
startActivity(targetIntent);
```

Receiving side :

```
Intent receiverIntent = getIntent().getBoolean("STATUS");
```